# how to make add button updates the total

Tags: angular, sum, addition

I am wondering how to make add button update in total with the price

```
 <table class=" container table table-striped table-hover ">
<thead>
  <tr>
   
    <th scope="col">Activity</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">1 hour</th>
    <th scope="col">30 min.</th>
    <th scope="col">Summary</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of bookAdd">
    <td>
      img
    </td>
    <td> {{item.name}} </td>
    <td *ngFor="let pointer of item.price; index as i" >{{pointer}}
      <button  type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Add</button>
    </td>
    
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td>
      <p>
        total
      </p>
    </td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
```

bookAdd: Booking[] = [];

constructor(private booking: BookingService,
private CartService: CartService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

```
this.booking.getBooking().subscribe((data) => {
  this.bookAdd = data;
  console.log(this.bookAdd);
});
```

}

}

[image for butter understanding the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n28CW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

For getting the total price for added booking,

1. Add `(click)` event to the button to call `addTotalPrice` method by passing the price (`pointer`).

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"
  (click)="addTotalPrice(pointer)"
>
  Add
</button>
```

2. Declare a `total` variable. Add `addTotalPrice` with one argument: `price` and sum with `total`.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  total = 0;

  ...

  addTotalPrice(price: number) {
    this.total += price;
  }
}
```

3. Render `total` in HTML.

```
<td>
  <p>
    {{ total }}
  </p>
</td>
```

---

**Solution 2**

Adding feature that you want to keep track for each item how many 1 hour, 30 mins are clicked.

1. Add `(click)` event to the button to call `addBookings` method by passing the `name`, price index (`i`) and price (`pointer`).

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"
  (click)="addBookings(item.name, i, pointer)"
>
  Add
</button>
```

2. 2.1. Create `booksSelected` array.

   2.2. Transform an array for `booksSelected` based on `bookAdd`. For each item add `priceSelected` (key-value pair with key is the price index (from `price` array) and value is selected time) and `subTotal` properties.

   2.3. Implement `addBookings` method. Aim to search the item from the `bookAdd` by name, then update the value of the filtered item for `priceSelected` and `subTotal` properties.

   2.4. Implement `bookingsTotal` getter by summing the `subTotal` for each item in `bookingsSelected`.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  
  booksSelected: any[] = [];

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookingService.getBooking().subscribe((data) => {
      this.bookAdd = data;
      console.log(this.bookAdd);

      this.booksSelected = data.map((x: any) => {
        x.priceSelected = x.price.reduce((acc, cur) => {
          let keyIndex = Object.keys(acc).length;

          acc[keyIndex] = 0;

          return acc;
        }, {});

        x.subTotal = 0;

        return x;
      });
    });
  }

  addBookings(name: string, i: number, price: number) {
    let index = this.booksSelected.findIndex((x) => x.name == name);
    this.booksSelected[i].priceSelected[i] += 1;
    this.booksSelected[i].subTotal += price;
  }

  get bookingsTotal() {
    return this.booksSelected.reduce((prev, cur) => {
      prev += cur.subTotal;

      return prev;
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

3. Render `bookingsTotal` in HTML.

```
<td>
  <p>
    {{ bookingsTotal }}
  </p>
</td>
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2vim54?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: thank you a lot this is very helpful, 
so how adding item name and price for each add
I want make a list of items that were added 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lIjWCVvz-iSm9MlHxWXLOA2c_Hka6SrB/view?usp=sharing